# Problems inserting document with Mongodb and Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

My logic app collects data from an api rest and inserts into a cosmosdb mongodb. The process occurs successfully, but when performing a query using Data Explorer the following error occurs:

```
Error while fetching page of documents: {"code":400,"body":"Command find failed: Unknown server error occurred when processing this request."}
```

Here is an example of a call that reproduces the error:

```
"Create_or_update_document": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "id": "11111",
                        "name": "john",
                        "surname": "doe"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('cockpit')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent('target-collection')}/docs"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
```

Example input:

```
{
  "id": "11111",
  "name": "john",
  "surname": "doe"
}
```

What I've been exploring is something related to the creation of the ObjectId. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the Azure Cosmos DB Logic Apps connector with the MongoDB API right now. It uses the SQL REST API under the hood at the moment.

I recommend you create a simple Azure Function that does the insert for you from a MongoDB Driver in your language of choice, then call that Function from Logic Apps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Connectors for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list) document,you could find the [~200+ connectors list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/).

Then navigate to the [Azure Cosmos DB Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/documentdb/), you could see the statement:

> To use this integration, you will need a Cosmos DB SQL API account
>   configured in the Azure Portal. Note that Mongo DB API accounts are
>   not currently supported.

Comment: I'm already using this connector. The problem comes from exactly it.

Comment: @brunormoreira Yeah,but your database is cosmos db mongo api which is not supported by Logic App.