# Logic App - PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I ran into this error while building a Logic App in Azure.  The solution to this [DocumentDB REST API: PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919885/documentdb-rest-api-partitionkey-extracted-from-document-doesnt-match) is not working.

My logic app receives a `POST` request with the raw JSON data, and then sends it to a Cosmos "Create or Update Document" step.  In there, I am able to specify my DB, and for my inputs, I have `body` and `headers` like so:

```
...
"inputs": {
   "body": "@triggerBody()",
   "headers": {
      "x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey": "@triggerBody()?['date']"
   },
   ...
}
...
```

My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "20190106",
  "date": "20190106",
  ...
}
```

In the error output, it literally shows my PartitionKey as `20190106`, so the `@triggerBody()?['date']` seems to have worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Logic Apps do not support the Mongo API.  Yes, there's a workaround, as in the Logic App can pass data from one endpoint to a serverless function that then writes to Mongo.

[Problems inserting document with Mongodb and Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368112/problems-inserting-document-with-mongodb-and-logic-apps)

Comment: The question doesn't mention Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add `Content-Type： application/json` in the Post request.(mentioned in this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c70e2f05-8d09-4cf5-9934-004593e263cd/error-in-logic-app-condition?forum=azurelogicapps))

Cosmos DB connector:

[image]

Post Request:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your partition key is date, then try passing the value of date  [“20190106"] (use the square brackets) in the partition key header. This worked for me 2 days ago using Rest API for CosmoDb.